# .NET Compile on Mac run on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, macos, mono

I have installed Xamarin and Mono on my Mac so that I can work with a C# project on the fly. I can run it on the Mac, however when i compile the project on my Mac and then run it on Windows (server 2003), I get an error message.

[image: error message]

Why is this?

Comment: Once you use something dynamic it is not easy to debug unless you know what you are attempting to call. Show the related code or nobody can help. Besides, Windows Server 2003 is end of life.

Comment: Well, if I compile the same code on Windows it will run on Windows. So that's why I am asking. If this might be a mono-related problem?

Comment: the two cases use different compilation tech so runtime behaviors vary. Besides, the BCLs differ. So you will have to dig further yourself, or reveal more info for others to help. There is no magic for others to simply tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Windows specific .dlls like Kernel32, etc. Removing these parts made it run on OS X and Linux.